# C++ class - finding car distance using x and y coordinates

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to find out how to deal with my piece of code. I need to find where the x and y values of the taxicab and see how far the taxicab traveled in relation to the direction the cab moves with x and y.

the first output is correct with 8 total spaces moved. however the second output is always incorrect. It is outputting 7 in relation to where the taxicab's current position is, but it should be located at -1.

I am aware that there is an error in where I entered my overloaded constructor. There is a answer with the use of an array and a pointer, but I haven't learned that in my class yet. I was hoping to see an alternative.

```
#ifndef TAXICAB_CPP
#define TAXICAB_CPP

class Taxicab
{
private:
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
    int totalDistance;
public:
    //constructors
    Taxicab(); //default constructor
    Taxicab(int, int); //overload constructor

    //accessors
    int getX(); //returns X
    int getY(); //returns Y
    int getDistanceTraveled();

    //mutators
    void moveX(int); //moves X 
    void moveY(int); //moves Y
};
#endif


//#include "Taxi.h" will need to divide the header file
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

Taxicab::Taxicab() //default constructor
{
    xCoord = 0;
    yCoord = 0;
    totalDistance = 0;
}

 Taxicab::Taxicab(int xCoord, int yCoord) //overload constructor
{
    //this->xCoord = xCoord; // while this works I cannot enter code with things I haven't learned yet.
    //this->yCoord = yCoord;
    totalDistance = 0;
}

int Taxicab::getX()
{
    return xCoord;
}

int Taxicab::getY()
{
    return yCoord;
}

void Taxicab::moveX(int X)
{
    totalDistance += abs(X);
    xCoord += X;
}

 void Taxicab::moveY(int Y)
{
     totalDistance += abs(Y);
     yCoord += Y;
}

int Taxicab::getDistanceTraveled()
{
    return totalDistance;
}

int main()
{
    Taxicab cab1;
    Taxicab cab2(5, -8);
    cab1.moveX(3);
    cab1.moveY(-4);
    cab1.moveX(-1);
    cout << cab1.getDistanceTraveled() << endl;
    cab2.moveY(7);
    cout << cab2.getY() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `abs` here?

Comment: to get the absolute value of the total distance travelled

Comment: @n.m - Think about it - if you travel +2 units along X and then travel -2 units along X, you've clearly travelled 4 units. Sure, your displacement from the starting position is 0, but you still had to burn enough petrol to travel 4 units.

Comment: Sorry misread the code, disregard the `abs` question. About your constructor: you don't have to use the same name (e.g. `xCoord`) for the constructor parameter and for the class member. Use different names, and you won't have to type `this->`. As the code stands now, it leaves `xCoord` and `yCoord` uninitialised, which is illegal.

Comment: "There is a answer with the use of an array and a pointer" --- don't even try to go near this.

Comment: `Taxicab(int a, int b) : xCoord(a), yCoord(b), totalDistance(0) {}`

Comment: @n.m - Thanks! That worked.